# iPad Development in a Frameset style

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am looking to design a Product Brochure application using xCode as an iPad app for a customer and due to my limited knowledge at this stage (but good at web dev) was wondering what implications there might be if I built the app in a frame set style loading my data from the web.

For example, I have a top menu which has the following headings.

Home - Products - Sectors - Contact

Obviously when the Products Link is clicked I would assume the standard thing to do would be to load the product images and data via XML into objective-C and parse them out in some kind of native application way.

My question is this. Is there a reason why I could not load a web application which shows the products on a kind of iPad view container and present all my information that way? Is it frowned upon at all?

I am limited in my xCode knowledge at the moment and wondered if this was a viable way of doing things? Obviously the user would need a web connection but that could be said for many apps out there.

Your thoughts on this would be most helpful? If what I am asking is not really a good idea I may have to contract out the work.

Thanks

Comment: add me in skype @ mcajigarpandya and I can be handy.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you mean to say that you create an app that contains one web view and that webview will present all the data from WEBSITE and that website you develop in HTML5 with logic as you explained. Nothing fency.. right?

In that case APPLE will reject your Apps on apple store and you will have only HTML5 based Website that can be render on any browser....

Your App need to have some native features else they will reject your app.

Comment: UIWebView :- You use the UIWebView class to embed web content in your application. To do so, you simply create a UIWebView object, attach it to a window, and send it a request to load web content. You can also use this class to move back and forward in the history of webpages, and you can even set some web content properties programmatically.